# I don't understand where is the error for my android apps

Tags: java, android

the codes are given below run properly but when I click the start activity button the apps shows the error: "Tasbeeh has unfortunately stopped"

here is my code

send.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvQuestion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I am a..." />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgAnswers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rCrazy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Crazy" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rSexy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SUPER SEXY" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rBoth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Both" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bReturn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Return" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the get.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etSend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSA"
    android:layout_below="@id/etSend"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="StartActivity" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSAFR"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bSA"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/bSA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="StartActivityForResult" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvGot"
    android:layout_below="@id/bSAFR"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Data.java

```
package com.firstone.nrshoukhin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Data extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button start, startFor;
EditText sendET;
TextView gotAnswer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.get);
    initialize();

}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSA);
    startFor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSAFR);
    sendET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSend);
    gotAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGot);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    startFor.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.bSA:
        String bread = sendET.getText().toString();
        Bundle basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key", bread);
        Intent a = new Intent(Data.this,OpenedClass.class);
        startActivity(a);
        break;
    case R.id.bSAFR:
        break;
    }

}

}
```

OpenedClass.java

```
package com.firstone.nrshoukhin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OpenedClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener{

TextView question, test;
Button returnData;
RadioGroup selectionList;
String gotBread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.send);
    intialize();
    Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
    gotBread = gotBasket.getString("key");
    question.setText(gotBread);
}

private void intialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
    test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);
    returnData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReturn);
    returnData.setOnClickListener(this);
    selectionList = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgAnswers);
    selectionList.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg1){
    case R.id.rCrazy:
        break;
    case R.id.rSexy:
        break;
    case R.id.rBoth:
        break;
    }
}

}
```

the log cat

```
12-11 23:14:25.726: D/dalvikvm(826): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 29K, 6% free 2555K/2704K,  paused 193ms, total 197ms
12-11 23:14:25.946: I/dalvikvm-heap(826): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.607MB for 4194320-byte allocation
12-11 23:14:26.086: D/dalvikvm(826): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 6651K/6804K, paused 137ms, total 137ms
12-11 23:14:30.746: D/gralloc_goldfish(826): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-11 23:14:34.366: D/dalvikvm(826): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 22K, 2% free 7922K/8064K, paused 149ms, total 165ms
12-11 23:14:34.805: I/Choreographer(826): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:14:35.705: I/Choreographer(826): Skipped 184 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:14:37.285: I/Choreographer(826): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:14:44.055: I/Choreographer(826): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:14:45.935: I/Choreographer(826): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:14:52.416: D/AndroidRuntime(826): Shutting down VM
12-11 23:14:52.416: W/dalvikvm(826): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.firstone.nrshoukhin.OpenedClass (has extras) }
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.firstone.nrshoukhin.Data.onClick(Data.java:48)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-11 23:14:52.506: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 23:15:01.525: I/Process(826): Sending signal. PID: 826 SIG: 9
12-11 23:15:03.145: D/dalvikvm(873): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 32K, 6% free 2556K/2708K, paused 41ms, total 44ms
12-11 23:15:03.187: I/dalvikvm-heap(873): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.608MB for 4194320-byte allocation
12-11 23:15:03.335: D/dalvikvm(873): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 6652K/6808K, paused 140ms, total 140ms
12-11 23:15:04.395: I/Choreographer(873): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:15:04.415: D/gralloc_goldfish(873): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-11 23:16:00.366: D/dalvikvm(918): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 36K, 6% free 2555K/2708K, paused 286ms, total 288ms
12-11 23:16:00.576: I/dalvikvm-heap(918): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.607MB for 4194320-byte allocation
12-11 23:16:00.696: D/dalvikvm(918): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 6651K/6808K, paused 116ms, total 117ms
12-11 23:16:03.667: D/gralloc_goldfish(918): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-11 23:16:07.086: D/dalvikvm(918): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 23K, 2% free 7924K/8064K, paused 184ms, total 204ms
12-11 23:16:07.906: I/Choreographer(918): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:16:13.015: I/Choreographer(918): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:16:14.605: I/Choreographer(918): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:16:19.175: I/Choreographer(918): Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:16:40.385: I/Choreographer(918): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:29:31.275: D/AndroidRuntime(966): Shutting down VM
12-11 23:29:31.295: W/dalvikvm(966): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.firstone.nrshoukhin; is package not installed?
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:509)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4417)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.firstone.nrshoukhin; is package not installed?
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:369)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:322)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
12-11 23:29:31.415: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  ... 11 more
12-11 23:29:43.665: D/dalvikvm(997): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 43K, 6% free 2555K/2716K, paused 144ms, total 158ms
12-11 23:29:43.865: I/dalvikvm-heap(997): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.607MB for 4194320-byte allocation
12-11 23:29:44.075: D/dalvikvm(997): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 6651K/6816K, paused 207ms, total 207ms
12-11 23:29:47.115: D/gralloc_goldfish(997): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-11 23:29:50.475: D/dalvikvm(997): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 23K, 2% free 7923K/8064K, paused 160ms, total 181ms
12-11 23:29:51.355: I/Choreographer(997): Skipped 110 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:29:54.466: I/Choreographer(997): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:29:56.016: I/Choreographer(997): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:29:59.826: D/AndroidRuntime(997): Shutting down VM
12-11 23:29:59.826: W/dalvikvm(997): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.firstone.nrshoukhin/com.firstone.nrshoukhin.OpenedClass}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at com.firstone.nrshoukhin.Data.onClick(Data.java:48)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-11 23:29:59.886: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 23:30:03.485: I/Process(997): Sending signal. PID: 997 SIG: 9
12-11 23:30:05.625: D/dalvikvm(1028): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 47K, 7% free 2556K/2720K, paused 209ms, total 215ms
12-11 23:30:05.725: I/dalvikvm-heap(1028): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.608MB for 4194320-byte allocation
12-11 23:30:05.855: D/dalvikvm(1028): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 6652K/6820K, paused 125ms, total 125ms
12-11 23:30:06.995: I/Choreographer(1028): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:30:07.015: D/gralloc_goldfish(1028): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-11 23:30:07.365: I/Choreographer(1028): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace please.

Comment: We need to see LogCat logs. Cannot say anything without it !

Comment: have u declared your class  OpenedClass  in  mainfest.

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that you didn't put your `Bundle` inside `Intent` object.

```
String bread = sendET.getText().toString();
Bundle basket = new Bundle();
basket.putString("key", bread);
Intent a = new Intent(Data.this,OpenedClass.class);
a.putExtras(basket);//set your bundle inside intent
startActivity(a);
```

Comment: This tried this code but unfortunately not working but this code is given below worked properly... could you please let me know what is the difference between two codes

    switch(arg0.getId()){
  case R.id.bSA:
   String bread = sendET.getText().toString();
   Bundle basket = new Bundle();
   basket.putString("key", bread);
   Intent a = new Intent("com.firstone.nrshoukhin.MENU");
   a.putExtras(basket);
   startActivity(a);
   break;
  case R.id.bSAFR:
   break;
  }

Comment: Intent a = new Intent("com.firstone.nrshoukhin.MENU");
@Noushad. That means that only activity that can process this type of action(this should be mentioned in Manifest file of those applications) will be notified, and you can choose one of them when startActivy(a); will be executed.
Check this link for better understanding.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html
If you still have some problems, please post your Manifest file.
I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
gotBread = gotBasket.getString("key");
```

The gotBasket is null, because you did not passed any extras when you started the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :In Data.java

```
    Intent a = new Intent(Data.this,OpenedClass.class);
    a.putExtra("key", bread);
```

And in OpenedClass.java:

```
Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
gotBread = gotBasket.getString("key");
```

And could You upload error log Then it will be easy to solve problem.

Declare OpenedClass in mainfest.